# Static local variable taking up no physical memory

Tags: c++, memory, static

I created the following functions to check the memory usage of static local variables and expected the array to take up roughly 5MB of memory but when I ran it the physical memory usage of the process was merely 0,2MB and went up when I actually set a value to each element in the array.

My understanding was that the array would be allocated memory when I first initialized it regardless of the values of elements in it. As I am able to access the first and the last element of the array where did the memory go inbetween?

```
void func() {
  static char a[5000000];
  a[0] = 'a';
  a[4999999] = 'a';
  cin >> a;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your operating system probably uses on-demand paging, and does not allocate pages to a process until they're actually used. You will learn more when you take a college-level course on operating system design and implementation. Now try making the array bigger, then writing to various parts of the array, and see what the resulting memory usage is.

Comment: The memory usage went up exponentially and was half the expected memory when I've written to 5000 random parts of the array so you were definitely correct. Thanks for the heads up about the course as well.

Comment: How did you measure memory?

Comment: I looked up the process on Windows Task Manager. The process was running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to **lazy memory allocation** or [zero fill on demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss), as explained below.

This is is explained in [zero initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) at cppreference:

> Zero initialization is performed in the following situations:
>
> 1 For every named variable with static or thread-local storage duration that is not subject to constant initialization (since C++14), before any other initialization.

So this variable qualifies. What does it mean *zero initialization*:

> The effects of zero initialization are:
>
> - If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral constant zero explicitly converted to T.
> - [...]  If T is array type, each element is zero-initialized

As an optimization, most modern systems don't even allocate any memory for zero initialized global/static variables, and that's why array size does not affect memory usage. What happens instead, the executable has a mark that says: "here should be zero values", and nothing more. When the program loads, all the addresses map to a small and shared read-only block of physical RAM that contains zeros.

Several virtual addresses can map to the same memory through a piece of hardware in the CPU which is called a "[Memory management unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)" (MMU). When the code attempts to write to the an address in the range, the MMU notifies the operating system (OS) that someone is writing a read-only block of memory, and the OS allocates the memory only then

Comment: A great example of why trying to apply naive, low-level 1970s-era "physical" expectations to a piece of C++ source code in 2019 is at best fraught with complications and at worst quite pointless. Just code to standards, unless you require hyperperformance or are trying to track down a nasty stack overflow bug or summat

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if I remember correctly, Linux has it since day one in early 90's. Windows-NT (a predecessor of Windows-10, early-mid 90's) also had it from day one. IRIX, Solaris, AIX and other unixen had it since late 80's (or earlier). This is old technology

Comment: Well then, quite!